# Strict/detailed iptables rules for i2p

Tags: firewall, iptables

I think I've understood the i2p faq correctly, and this appears to work (added the wording from the faq followed by the rules, in order, and changed my unique port number to PORT):

```
# Outbound UDP from the random port noted on the configuration page
# to arbitrary remote UDP ports, allowing replies
-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport PORT -j ACCEPT

# Outbound TCP from random high ports to arbitrary remote TCP ports
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 9000:31000 -j ACCEPT

# Inbound UDP to the port noted on configuration page from arbitrary locations
-A INPUT -p udp --dport PORT -j ACCEPT

# Inbound TCP to the port noted on configuration page from arbitrary locations
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport PORT -j ACCEPT

# Outbound UDP on port 123, allowing replies
-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

But since I have an i2p user and all, would perhaps this be better?

```
-A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m owner --uid-owner i2p
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m owner --uid-owner i2p
```

Is the former more secure because it doesn't allow a user free pass through the firewall as it likes? Or is the latter more secure because only ports used by the user will be open at any moment?

Also, I'm assuming NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED state on all, but perhaps some should just be ESTABLISHED or something, like the outbound rule for tcp on the range of ports 9000-31000?